# Why is necessary to first catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and then IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception

Let's take as reference the next code:

```
try{
   /*Code that may throw IndexOutOfBoundsException or ArrayIndexOut......*/
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    /*handle*/
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    /*handle*/
}
```

- Why doesn't this compile, but if a switch the sequence of catch clauses it does compile?
- Maybe I must first write a specific exception and then a more general?

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a parent of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so the other catch will never be invoked.

Comment: first need to catch more specific exception.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that you'll need different handling, so why not just catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and handle both in one catch block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) extends from [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html), which means the first one is more specific than the second one.

So if there is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it is matched to an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`: in other words, the catch for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be unreachable.

For all exceptions declared in your `catch`es to be reachable, you need to order them from the most specific to the most generic ones.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a subclass of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so the second clause is unreachable because the first one will always catch the exception.